# One Row to Match Them All

Tags: mysql, join

So I have a situation where I have two tables. One is the base table (called `_Keys` in this example), with a unique primary key. Then there is another table with multiple rows of a data for each id in _Keys (this second table is `Extra`).

I need to select the largest value for each primary key in _Keys from Extra. I have made an SQLFiddle to model the problem [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/830c1/3).

This is the query I'm currently using, but the issue is that it will only select one value for the Extra table, not one value per row.

```
Select * from _Keys
LEFT JOIN
(Select * from Extra ORDER BY value2 DESC LIMIT 1) as e
ON e.id = _Keys.id;
```

For my example SQL Fiddle I used this database schema:

```
CREATE TABLE _Keys(id int, value int);
INSERT INTO _Keys (id, value) VALUES (1, 5),(2, 3),(3, 4);

CREATE TABLE Extra(id int, value2 int);
INSERT INTO Extra (id, value2) VALUES (1, 3),(1, 1),(2, 4),(2, 6),(3, 3),(3, 5);
```

Basically my result is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/830c1/3). Only the first row from the _Keys table gets its data from the second table.

In MySQL, how can I achieve selecting one row from Extras for each row in _Keys?

Comment: Can you post your tables (schema) as well?

Comment: One Row to find them, One Row to bring them all, and in the data bind them?

Comment: @CCovey It can only be destroyed in _The Cracks in Data Structure_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I understand what you are trying to do but I'm not sure.

- You are getting `NULL` values because of the `LIMIT`, it only returns the first row. You also need to use `GROUP BY`.
- To get the largest value, your can use `MAX`.

Try this.

```
SELECT * from _Keys
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT id, MAX(value2) AS value2 FROM Extra GROUP BY id) as e
ON e.id = _Keys.id;
```

Comment: Ok, this seems to be what I need. Just need to check, then I'll accept.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this query with better performance :

```
SELECT k.id, MAX(e.value2) AS value2
FROM _Keys k
INNER JOIN Extra e
ON (k.id = e.id)
GROUP BY k.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your joined table `Select * from Extra ORDER BY value2 DESC LIMIT 1` will contain only one row because of LIMIT. Try this:

```
Select * from _Keys
LEFT JOIN
(Select id, max(value2) from Extra group by id) as e
ON e.id = _Keys.id;
```